# Javascript, display results when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick

The user is supposed to enter gender and age, click on the button, and some text and images will be displayed. When I click the button, nothing happens. I am a student/javaScript beginner and quite new to this. I am aware that the code is not complete :)   -  Can anyone give me some advice?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Et forslag</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1>FindYourLove</h1>
        </header>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="alle-profiler.html">Alle profiler</a></li>
                <li><a href="profil-forslag.html">Dagens profil</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <main>
        
            <section>
                <label>Tast inn ønsket alder</label>
                <input type="text" id="alder-p"><br>
                <label>Mann eller kvinne?</label>
                <input type="text" id="gender-p">
                <input id="forslag-btn" type="button" value="Vis forslag">
                <p id="output-p"></p>
            </section>
            
            <script>
                function visBruker(){
                var alder = document.getElementById("alder-p");
                var kjønn = document.getElementById("gender-p");
                }
                    
                var outputP = document.getElementById("output-p");
                var forslagBtn = document.getElementById("forslag-btn");
                
                
                if( kjønn == mann && alder >= 25){
                    outputP.innerHTML = "Simen";   
                }
                else if( kjønn == mann && alder =<25 ){
                   
                }
                else if( kjønn == kvinne && alder >= 25){
                    
                }
                else{
                    
                }
                
                
            </script> 
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create this code, it works fine, I hope it will helps you. Let me know if you need more help.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("forslag-btn");
const outputP = document.getElementById("output-p");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const alder = document.getElementById("alder-p").value;
  const kjønn = document.getElementById("gender-p").value;
  if (kjønn === "mann") {
    if (alder >= 25) {
      outputP.innerText = "Simen";
    } else {
      console.log("y");
    }
  }
  if (kjønn === "kvinne") {
    if (alder >= 25) {
      console.log("x");
    } else {
      console.log("y");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add onclick event handler to the button so that your function gets executed whenever you click it.

`<input id="forslag-btn" type="button" value="Vis forslag" onclick="visBruker()">`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your script to run as a event onclick function. What you have right now runs when the page loads. The onclick function would be added to the button html element.

```
<button onclick="function()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the onClick attribute and set it to the function you want to run when the button is clicked. If you are trying to have things hidden in the background and display them onClick you can use the `display: none` and have the script show the images & text on button click.

```
<input id="forslaf-btn" type="button" value="Vis forslag onClick="visBruker">
```